# Cannot deserialize Timer info object with ClassNotFoundException on JBoss

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, timer, jboss5.x

I created a [`Timer`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/ejb/Timer.html) with a `TimerVO` that implements `Serializable` as the timer's [info](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/ejb/Timer.html#getInfo%28%29) and added to [`TimeService`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/ejb/TimerService.html#createTimer%28long,%20long,%20java.io.Serializable%29). The `TimerVO` simply holds the id of the object that will be processed on timeout.

```
timerService.createTimer(60000, 60000, new TimerVo(objectId, TIMER_NAME));
```

When the node is started, the timers are all created correctly, i can see the logging from the timeout method, and they are persisted in JBoss' hypersonic database in `data/hypersonic/localDB.script`, however when the node is restarted i get a `ClassNotFoundException` on startup when the timers are restored by the containers.

```
2010-11-25 21:40:25,171 ERROR (main) [org.jboss.ejb.txtimer.GeneralPurposeDatabasePersistencePlugin] Cannot deserialize
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: exam.ejb.TimerVo
```

Why am i getting the `ClassNotFoundException` and is there a way to solve it?

EJB3.0, Java 1.6, JBoss 5.1.0.GA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a classloader issue. I moved the `TimerVo` to a separate jar that i deployed in the `node03/lib` directory and i didn't get the errors. I have raised a [bug](https://jira.jboss.org/browse/JBAS-8671) issue on JBoss' bug tracker.